# Group by Time Interval

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I need to Group my Table into 15 minutes Intervals. I can do that with:

```
select dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, ts) / 15 * 15, 0), sum (goodpieces) 
from StationCount 
Group by dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, ts) / 15 * 15, 0)
```

But to display the returned data in a chart i need to insert also the intervals which don't have any data and aren't currently appearing in my select statement. How do i insert these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a table with every possible timestamp in 15 minute increments, and do a LEFT JOIN from it to your query above.

```
SELECT * FROM timestamps LEFT JOIN (SELECT dateadd......) ON timestamps.timestamp = StationCount.ts
```

If you know your chart always covers a 24 hour period, you only need to create a table with the numbers 0-95, then for each entry add it to the start time of your chart.

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT dateadd(minute, <starttime>, number*15) timestamp FROM numbers) timestamps LEFT JOIN
       (SELECT dateadd......) ON timestamps.timestamp = StationCount.ts
```

Comment: Can you tell me why the numbers table should have 95 entries for 24 hours?

Comment: 96 entries, not 95 (0-95 inclusive) because 24*60/15=96.

Comment: Ok, Aren't u missing number *15 in the first part of your select ?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might help you.

```
declare @startDate datetime
        ,@endDate datetime

set @startDate = '2011-10-25'
set @endDate = '2011-10-26'

;with fifteenMinutes
as
(
    select  dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, @startDate) / 15 * 15, 0) as q
    UNION ALL
    select  dateadd(minute, 15, q)
    from fifteenMinutes
    where q < @endDate
)

select * from fifteenMinutes
```