# Finding records within a 5 min time interval in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, time, intervals

I have a table with over 100,000 rows that contain the following columns: ID, Time, and Boolean.
The time column tracks time down to the second.
I need a query that will find all instances of Boolean = 1 for every 5 minute interval of time from the start of the table to the end, then group the count by time interval.

The table represents 4 hours of data, so I should get 48 rows of results.
I'm using MS SQL Server.

I've tried a few approaches, but the time interval logic is giving me a hard time.

EDIT: I figured it out!

```
SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, timestamp)/5 * 5,0), COUNT(*)  
FROM table  
WHERE isrepeat = 1  
GROUP BY by DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, timestamp)/5 * 5,0)  
ORDER BY by 1
```

Comment: Take a look at this SO thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992252/group-by-time-interval

Answer (score 2):

This should do. You can group by your results by an interval of time/5.

```
select
cast(to_char(Time, 'mi') as int) / 5 * 5 || ' - ' || cast(to_char(Time, 'mi') as int) / 5 * 5 + 5 as "Interval",
count(1)
from tableName
where
Boolean = 1
group by
cast(to_char(Time, 'mi') as int) / 5
```

Comment: This would be a valid answer for **ORACLE**

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from tableName where Time 
BETWEEN DATEADD(minute, -5, current_timestamp)
AND current_timestamp
```